# How to access signalr server side logs in .net core

Tags: logging, signalr, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-signalr

recently we've been having problems between our backend (**.net core 2.2**) & frontend apps (**angular 8**) when they connect via **signalr**. I've implemented logging to azure insights on the front end, but am getting nowhere with the backend. What we need is basically to catch the signalr logs and log them to our ***azure insights page*** (or wherever).

Following [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-3.1), it shows how to enable the signalr logs, but nowhere does it say how to catch them. The only information they give is to enable Application Logging (Filesystem) on Azure app service portal. However, doing this one can either - read current logs as they come, or access them on a file server. I've gone through the fileserver but couldn't find anything useful (not just signalr).

What we want is to simply **catch signalr logs** and **forward them to our App Insights page**, just like any other telemetry.

Comment: I believe the app insights will only catch the SignalR ERROR logs, not just normal logs.

Comment: What do you mean? It's possible to configure the log levels to catch from signalr, as so:                    
                    logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections", LogLevel.Debug); 
But how to catch them is the question

Comment: Yes, you configure the logs, but to access the logs from the App Insights, you only have access to the log on the stack trace from a error.

Comment: What you trying to archive is the completed log for each connection or SignalR action?

Comment: Yes I want access to the internal signalr logs (AspNetCore.SignalR & AspNetCore.Http.Connections), on the level I set them, which is currently LogLevel.Debug.

Comment: Do you want to [use ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider to capture ILogger logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#aspnet-core-applications)?

Comment: Maybe I can set this up to catch signalr logs, I'll try it out. If you have any ideas how to test it (ie produce signalr warning/critical errors), Id appreciate it